# Overridden Edit button with Visualforce page is not visible on community

Tags: templates, salesforce, visualforce, lightning

I have overridden a custom object Edit/New button with Visualforce page to leverage some functionalities like adding text instruction on filling up the form, ajax functionality to fetch information based on conditions etc . However I cannot view the button on Community.

I am using **Napili** theme on community, I know it does not supports Visualforce but how can I add a lightning component  or something to override the records edit page.

Do I need to create a custom Tab for viewing the record list using lightning component and then eventually will have to create Detail, New, View pages? How could we achieve it if its possible ? Looks lot of work and maintenance in future for this option.

Please help me on this.

Comment: could you show your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have overridden Edit and New buttons on standard object by a visualforce page. The main purpose of going to Visualforce page is to show instructions on the header before user submits the request. I suggested to use help text but the instructions are huge so we had to go for visualforce to cater this.